# Generating CRUD in symfony 4

Tags: crud, symfony4

After releasing Symfony 4.0, there is no support for `SensioGeneratorBundle`. hence the command `php app/console generate:doctrine:crud` is not available.

They suggest to use **MakerBundle**, but I could not find appropriate replacement for CRUD generation.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the [`make`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html) command in Symfony4+ (and it's quite an improvement!), from the [MakerBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html):

```
php bin/console make:crud
```

It'll prompt you for which entity you want the crud for. It generates a controller with index, new, update, view and delete methods in `/src/controller`, with matching templates in `/templates`.

**Useful to know**: If you run `make:entity`, and later run that command again and enter an existing entity, it responds with:

> Your entity already exists! So let's add some new fields!

Answer (score 4):

At the moment `MakerBundle` supports just a few core commands. You can see the list [here](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/tree/master/src/Maker). Unfortunately there's no CRUD generator. But there some [discussion about it](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/3) in the issues so you can follow what will be done.

If what you need is just a generator for boilerplate code and not a more structured solution like [EasyAdminBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html) you should consider [creating your own maker](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html#creating-your-own-makers).

Comment: Thanks @dlondero Another question is that where's Symfony 4 debug toolbar?

Comment: I found it, according to documents Profiler component must be installed.

Comment: I was looking for this functionality and stumbled upon this answer. Since the latest release on March 14th, 2018 the `make:crud` command was added: https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/releases/tag/v1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Symfony4 (thanks to @jelle)

```
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev

composer require symfony/form symfony/validator symfony/twig-bundle symfony/orm-pack symfony/security-csrf

php bin\console make:crud

The class name of the entity to create CRUD (e.g. BravePuppy):
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

first install pre-req packages

```
composer require twig-bundle security-csrf
```

and then you can run

```
php bin/console make:crud
```

after that just enter your entity name which you want to curd

```
The class name of the entity to create CRUD (e.g. BlogPosts):
 >
```