# Symfony 4 doctrine - create entity and controller for new database table

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I am very new to Symfony and Doctrine.
I needed to add a new table to the existing database and i would like to create the entity and controller for this new table.
Is there a command to do this for just one table?  I have tried the following command:

```
bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert --from-database annotation src/CRM/CRMBundle/Entity/ --force
```

When i run this command, all of the entities are recreated and the namespace is removed.  I am only interested in creating 1 new entity and controller for the new table.  Is this possible?  Is there a similar solution if i would like to add columns to an existing table that already has an Entity and Controller created?

Comment: `bin/console make:entity` creates Entity, table and Repository.

Comment: does the new table name go at the end of this command? bin/console make:entity <table name>   How to specify the path where the entity should be created?

Comment: Just type it, everything is explained after that

Comment: I see this can make a new entity but why aren't the fields automatically pulled from the new database table?  There's no way to automatically create the entity based on the table fields?

Comment: This also created the entity in /src/entity  i would like it the entity to be created in a different location. is that possible?

Comment: I guess you can just move it afterward (taking care about the namespace though). Not sure if you can do it at creation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184816/discussion-between-jules-r-and-user2370664).

Answer (score 0):

```
bin/console make:crud
```

More details about it you can read [hier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845622/generating-crud-in-symfony-4) and [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#generating-controllers)

Comment: Add more details to your answer and then references.